# Create a single, custom, globally available object in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am having a very difficult time finding the answer to this. I want to create a custom class (this I know how to do) and have it get instantiated--one instance--that is globally accessible from within my application. I am looking to centralize and abstract some code and use this globally-available object as an interface. I can't believe how weird this is to figure out.

I need to have models, etc., available from within this object.

Help is appreciated.

I am running Rails 3.2.8.

Answer (score 1):

Any model that you put in `app/models` will be autoloaded by Rails, so you can stick a custom model there.

The class will be available throughout your app, so whether you can just use class methods or not is up to you. If you want it to be a singleton, see [this helpful article](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/9-ruby-singleton-pattern-again).

Lastly, if you need the model to instantiate in some specific way, just put it in an [initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files). Any file in `config/initializers` will be run once as the app boots up.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a Singleton...

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html

However, that will only be available to that apps process. If you run multiple app servers (ie. multiple thin instances or Passenger) each will have it's own instance.

If you need something truly global you'll have to look into other options.